# More efficient way to find matching friday to monday in data set

Tags: dataframe, stock

The code is to retrieve the corresponding friday data for a given stock dataframe. I believe the code works as intended but I figure there was a more effective way for time complexity. Would querying the data frame for the datetime index of monday adjusted to friday be more efficient. If so please explain the time complexity of this compared to my code. I believe the time complexity for my code is O(4n).

```
for i in range(len(df)-5):
    row=df.iloc[i]
    if row['DayOfWeek']==0:
        for j in range(i+1,i+5): #starting with tues check next 4 tradings days for a friday
            frow=df.iloc[j] #friday row
            if frow['DayOfWeek']==4:
                diff=frow['Close']-row['Close']
                start=row['Date']
                mf_df=mf_df.append(pd.DataFrame([diff],[start]))
```

Comment: 'DayOfWeek' is a Datetime column

Comment: Might be helpful to tag the programming language here, to get more visibility.